# Printing the calculated distance in SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgis, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy with Postgres, Postgis and GEOAlchemy. I am able to sort entries in a table according to a point submitted by the user. I wonder how I could also return the calculated distance...

This is how I sort the items:

```
result = Event.query.order_by(func.ST_Distance(Event.address_gps, coordinates_point)).paginate(page, 10).items

for result in results:
    result_dict = result.to_dict()

return result_dict
```

according to the users position (coordinates_point). I would like to add an entry in each result in the result_dict which also contains the distance that the item was ordered by. How do I do that? What does func.ST_Distance return?

I tried to add this in the for loop above:

```
current_distance = func.ST_Distance(Event.address_gps, coordinates_point)
result_dict['distance'] = current_distance
```

But that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [column labels](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.label)

```
query = Event.query.with_entities(Event, func.ST_Distance(Event.address_gps, coordinates_point).label('distance')).order_by('distance')
results = query.paginate(page, 10).items
for result in results:
    event = result.Event
    distance = result.distance
    result_dict = event.to_dict()
    result_dict['distance'] = distance
```

Comment: Thanks! Works as expected :) Which unit do I get the distance in?

Comment: It depends on the CRS of the geom you're using to calculate the distance. WGS 84, a common CRS, [uses degrees](https://epsg.io/4326) as the unit, for example. The US National Atlas Equal Area CRS [uses meters](https://epsg.io/2163).

Comment: Is there a way to specify max distance using ST_Distance?